# How to change a emission material via code using FOR loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an animation where I'm using an emission material and I'm trying to turn on and off that emission using a FOR loop. To be more specific...

**I have this function which I'm using to set the emission:**

```
void TurnOnLight(bool on)
    {
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        Material mat = renderer.material;
        Color baseColor = Color.yellow;
        float emission;
        Color finalColor;
        if (on)
        {
            emission = 1;
            finalColor = baseColor * Mathf.LinearToGammaSpace(emission);
        }
        else
        {
            emission = 0;
            finalColor = baseColor * Mathf.LinearToGammaSpace(emission);
        }
        mat.SetColor("_EmissionColor", finalColor);
    }
```

**And a function where I'm set this on and off with a delay (but I don't know how to set that delay):**

```
void blink(void){
    TurnOnLight(true);
    //something to make a delay(wait) of 1 second
    TurnOnLight(false);
    //something to make a delay(wait) of 1 second
}
```

**And a FOR loop where I'm trying to make and on-off effect on that light:**

```
for(int i=0;i<50;i++){ 
     blink();
}
```

Now I have 2 question here...

1. How to make that for loop to actually works? Because in this moment my light will be always off because my last call function will be like this **TurnOnLight(false);** inside of **blink()** function. Where exactly should I put that FOR loop?
2. How exactly can I make that part with **//something to make a delay(wait) of 1 second**? I've tried with [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) but is not working well...

Comment: 1. `System.Thread.Sleep(1000);` 2. Why not add an extra call to `TurnOnLight(true);` after the end of the for loop? 3. I don't know Unity at all; does this actually work?

Comment: @EdPlunkett if by "work" you mean "completely freeze the entire program" then sure. `Thread.Sleep` is not an appropriate solution to *anything.*

Comment: @Draco18s Well, they'd better get rid of it then.

Comment: @EdPlunkett More correctly, `Thread.Sleep` *should never be called on the main application thread.* It is fine to use in a coroutine.

Comment: @Draco18s 100% agreement. I thought it possible that the code *was* in a coroutine, since the tags mentioned threading. My point 3 could have been more clearly stated.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I must correct myself, as well. Unity coroutines [aren't threads](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/15501/view.html). So `Thread.sleep` inside one is also wrong. It *is* fine inside am actual child thread however, which is what I was getting at.

Comment: @Draco18s Ah, OK, I thought "co-routine" was just a fancy computer-science term for "thread". I think we're still in agreement though.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I did too up until a few days ago when I read something that explains what they actually did. I forget where, but it had something to do with the WaitForSrconds only being approximate because the coroutine was checked every frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use coroutines as follow :

```
public IEnumerator blink( int count, float onDuration, float offDuration )
{
    WaitForSeconds onWait = new WaitForSeconds( onDuration ) ;
    WaitForSeconds offWait = new WaitForSeconds( offDuration ) ;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i )
    {
        TurnOnLight(true);
        yield return onWait ;
        TurnOnLight(false);
        yield return offWait ;
    }
    // If you want your light to be turned on in the end
    TurnOnLight(true);
}
```

Then, call it :

```
StartCoroutine( blink( 50, 1, 1 ) ) ;
```